# aesara/tensor: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'type'

Tags: tensor, pymc

I'm bulding a model using pymc and aesara. The model worked fine until I introduce the new parameter 'cut_off'. It throws me this error: **AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'type'**. I've shorten the code so that it's easy to find the mentioned parameter.

```
def logp_5_3(y, p, cut_off, dist_raise_first, dist_reduce_first, previous_y, major_y, major_per):
    phi = [None] * 5

    ......
    phi[4] = at.switch( #bias
        at.eq(y,1), 0, at.switch(
             at.ge(major_per, cut_off), at.switch(at.eq(y, major_y), 1, 0), 0
        )
    )

    # Compute log ( p_s * Pr(y_i|s) )
    for i in range(5):
        phi[i] = at.log(phi[i]) + at.log(p[i])

    # Compute average log-probability of y_i
    return at.sum(pm.math.logsumexp(phi, axis=0))
```

```
with pm.Model() as m6_model5_3:
    #prior
    p = pm.Dirichlet('p', np.array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4]))
    cut_off = pm.Beta('cut_off', 0.5, 1)

    #likelihood
    likelihood = pm.DensityDist('y6', p, cut_off,..., logp = logp_5_3, observed=result['choice'].tolist())
    trace_6_model5_3 = pm.sample() #estimate parameter based on data
```